# How to get the Euclid distance from specified array in numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to generate specific array by calculating Euclid distance, I'm getting a different result

```
import numpy
def find_eucledian_distances(a_points, b_points):
  return numpy.sqrt(numpy.sum((a_points-b_points)**2))

a = np.array([[3.0, 4.0],
          [-3.0, -6.0],
          [-2.5, 6.3]])
b = np.array([[0.0, 0.0],
          [2.0, 6.0],
          [4.5, -8.3]])
d = find_eucledian_distances(a, b)

print(d)
print(d.shape)
```

These are two expected results 
expected result: [  5.        13.          16.19135572] 
expected result: (3,)

but I'm getting 21.35790251873999 as a result. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should return bellows:

```
return  numpy.sqrt(numpy.sum((a_points-b_points)**2, axis=-1))
```

you should `np.sum` along the last axis. if you don't specific the `axis=-1`, the `np.sum()` will sum all of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

There is a numpy inbuilt way for this with the numpy's **lin**ear **alg**ebra library `linalg`:

```
return numpy.linalg.norm(a_points-b_points, axis=-1)
```

Comment: Can you help me understand one more problem @Ashan Priyadarshana ?

Comment: Yes please go ahead

Comment: Trying to understand this question                                                                        $$
y = sin(x) + cos(\sqrt{3} \; x)
$$

A vectorized function that takes a NumPy array of x values as its input parameter, and returns a new array of the resulting y values computed for each of the x values in the array.

Then  trying to plot the function using a basic Matplotlib plot.  Plot range of x values from -20.0 to 20.0. I have to use at least 1000 points in that range to create your plot.

Comment: `x = numpy.random.uniform(-20.0, 20.0, size=1000)`
`x = np.sort(x)`
`y = numpy.sin(x) + numpy.cos(numpy.sqrt(3) * x)`
`plt.plot(x,y)`

Comment: is there any way that I can directly contact you via any media?